# Data contract serialization for WCF web service request

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer

I have a DataContract element for my WCF web service request as follow:

```
    [DataContract]
    public sealed class Request
    {
       public int EventID { get; set; }
    }
```

Once my web service runs, my request generated from the wsdl looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
          <tem:EventDismissRequest>
              <tem:request/>
          </tem:EventDismissRequest>
      </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, I wants it to be like below, which mean my event id is nested in a request element with no tem prefix.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
          <tem:EventDismissRequest>
             <request>
               <EventID>?</EventID>
             <request>
          </tem:EventDismissRequest>
      </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I think I have to do some xml attribute within my datacontract but there are many options and I've tried numerous methods without success.

Comment: You need to decorate EventID with a `[DataMember]` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the attribute you need is [Serializable] as follows, along with [DataMember] for each item you wish to serialize.

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public sealed class Request
{
   [DataMember]
   public int EventID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, your suggestion works well but I see <tem:request>, is there away for me to omit the tem and leave with <request>?

Comment: What version of WCF you using?  I don't see that in mine

Comment: probably have something to do with xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" that I have in my envelope that I see within SOAPUi

Comment: After poking around I get it to work with [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]